# stickyClass is not defined in magento 2.2.0

Tags: error, magento2.2, backend

```
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return stickyClass }"
Message: stickyClass is not defined
    at css (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:56)
    at update (knockout.js:3803)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
    at knockout.js:3002
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
    at Object.ko.applyBindings (knockout.js:3065)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this problem was appeared on the admin grid page of a third-party or own extension, try to delete (or temporary comment) code below from UI listing file
(Ex: Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/entity_listing.xml):

```
<container name="sticky">
  ...         
</container>
```

**But!** This solve isn't a 100% fix and hides js error only.
The really problem may be in the functionality of the top sticky header with the filters and additional elements, which has been written and worked for the 2.0.x magento and doesn't  work correctly in newer magento:

[image]

In this case you need change extension's UI listing for compatibility with needed magento version.